# flask to execute other tasks after return render_template

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

In flask app, I need to execute other task's `checkJob` function (checking the job status and email to the the user) after executing `return render_template(page)`. The user will see the confirm page but there is still background job running to check the job status.

I tried to use celery https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask for the background job and it does not work. Anything after `return render_template(page)` is not being executed.

Here's the code fragment:

```
@app.route("/myprocess", methods=['POST'])
def myprocess():
    //.... do work
    #r = checkJob()
    return render_template('confirm.html')
    r = checkJob()

@celery.task()
def checkJob():
    bb=1
    while bb == 1:
       print "checkJob"
       time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: you can't run anything after `return` because `return` ends (every) function, it leaves function immediatelly. You have to do before `return` using `checkJob.delay()`

Comment: Thanks @furas. I tried to put checkJob.delay() before return statement, but the problem is the confirm.html is not displayed and waiting for checkJob to finished. Is there a way I can display confirm.html immediately and then execute checkJob task? Thanks so much!!

Comment: As I can see, you have not tried to use Celery.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. How can you tell I am not using Celery? Could you please tell me what mistake I made? I followed the example in https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

Comment: If you read that article why don't you call celery task with `.delay()` or `.apply_async()`?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you should use `apply_async()`.

```
@app.route("/myprocess", methods=['POST'])
def myprocess():
    #.... do work
    r = checkJob.apply_async()
    return render_template('confirm.html')
```

Note that, as with the [example](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask), you do not want to invoke `checkJob()` but rather keep it like `checkJob`.

Comment: I have tried to do that but still does not execute anything in checkJob. The example us @celery.task, not @celery.task(), and I tried that too but just not doing anything@celery.task()
def checkJob():
    bb=1
    while bb == 1:
       print "checkJob"
       time.sleep(10)